# Event listener gets attached inconsequently

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain why does clicking on second "Show details" will not work unless previous "Show details" is already clicked (except for the first "Show details", this will always work)? How can I make every toggle work, regardless of clicking order (ideally, keeping the for loop).

```js
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('.details-toggle')
toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement
    const details = parent.nextElementSibling
    let opacity = details.style.opacity === "0" ? "1" : "0"
    let maxHeight = details.style.maxHeight === "0px" ? "1000px" : "0px"
    details.style.opacity = opacity
    details.style.maxHeight = maxHeight
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <head>
  </head>

  <body>

    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          Title
          <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
        </div>
        <div class="details" style="opacity: 0; max-height: 0px">
          <ul>
            <li>Det 1</li>
            <li>Det 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>
          Title
          <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
        </div>
        <div class="details" style="opacity: 0; max-height: 0px">
          <ul>
            <li>Det 1</li>
            <li>Det 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>

      <li>
        <div>
          Title
          <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
        </div>
        <div class="details" style="opacity: 0; max-height: 0px">
          <ul>
            <li>Det 1</li>
            <li>Det 2</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The ul element is over the following element. Eight click and inspect and you will see if will inspect the previous element's child li. Set the opacity to one and you will see it. You are not using transitions, so not sure why you are not just toggling display.

Comment: This is really weird I removed the loop added onclick to each and then what same problem ! Nice one

Comment: Do it [this way](https://jsfiddle.net/z3p9faL7/).

Comment: Got it man no js just inline CSS was creating this weird problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your loop. It has to do with the fact that by just changing the opacity of your "hidden" elements they are still there, and actually overlay your other 2 "show details" elements so they never receive the click.

You can fix this by changing the display to `none` and then they actually *do* receive the click.

```js
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('div .details-toggle')
toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement
    const details = parent.nextElementSibling
    console.log(details.style.display);
  })
})
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      Title
      <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
    </div>
    <div class="details" style="display:none">
      <ul>
        <li>Det 1</li>
        <li>Det 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>
      Title
      <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
    </div>
    <div class="details" style="display:none">
      <ul>
        <li>Det 1</li>
        <li>Det 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>
      Title
      <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
    </div>
    <div class="details" style="display:none">
      <ul>
        <li>Det 1</li>
        <li>Det 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would suggest you control the visibility of these detail elements by toggling a class to show/hide:

```js
const toggles = document.querySelectorAll('div .details-toggle')
toggles.forEach(toggle => {
  toggle.addEventListener('click', e => {
    const parent = e.target.parentElement
    const details = parent.nextElementSibling
    details.classList.toggle("hidden");
  })
})
```

```css
.hidden{
   display:none
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <div>
      Title
      <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
    </div>
    <div class="details hidden">
      <ul>
        <li>Det 1</li>
        <li>Det 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>
      Title
      <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
    </div>
    <div class="details hidden">
      <ul>
        <li>Det 1</li>
        <li>Det 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>
      Title
      <small class="details-toggle">Show details</small>
    </div>
    <div class="details hidden">
      <ul>
        <li>Det 1</li>
        <li>Det 2</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```